# get unselected datagrid row jquery easyui

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I'm using the [jQuery EasyUI datagrid](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/datagrid.php) to present some data to my users. I know how to get the data of the row that is selected in the datagrid by using:

```
var selectedRow = $('#my_datagrid_id').datagrid('getSelected');
```

But does anybody know how I can get a particular row in my datagrid by its id or something (without having the row selected)?

I can't seem to find anywhere how to do this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this one, then I think you will know what to do next :)

var myData = $('#my_datagrid_id').datagrid('getData');
alert('myData : ' + JSON.stringify(myData));
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try,

if you want to get the row with Id "01",

```
var row=$('#my_datagrid_id').datagrid('getRows')[$('#my_datagrid_id').datagrid('getRowIndex','01')];
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use... `getRows` to get all the rows and loop thourgh the rows..

```
 var rows=$('#my_datagrid_id').datagrid('getRows');
 if(rows.length == 0)
 {
     alert('no row present');
 }else{
    for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
       //do your stuff here.. if your want particular row then u can use if condition 
    }
 }
```

**OR**

if u know the index of the row u wanted, then u can use `getRowIndex` method

go through the documentaion [here](http://jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

As you know to find all rows you should try this:

```
var allRows = $('#my_datagrid_id').datagrid('getRows');
```

To get selected rows:

```
var selectedRows = $('#my_datagrid_id').datagrid('getSelections');
```

Suppose you know Index of your particular row which we assume this Index as 5. To find if this special row is get selected or not:

```
var specialRow= $.grep(selectedRows , function (e) {
   return e == allRows[5];
});
if(specialRow.length>0)
alert('Voila! The Row is selected');
else
alert('Nope! The Row is not selected');
```

By `$.grep` you can search in an array (in our context, in selected rows) and if your particular row was inside the array(selected rows) you will be returned with a filled specialRow array.